# Journal Posting Working On Test Environment But Getting Unauthorized on Production

Tags: c#, access-token, production-environment, xero-api, test-environments

We're posting journal reports to Xero on the trial Xero account

Everything is working fine locally and on a test environment (When deployed).

But when deployed to the production environment, we're unable to get the access-token therefore getting an unauthorized response.

I've shared the demo account details below.

Company (Demo): company name

App name: dev-test

client_id: 13*****************23

Time zone: GMT +1 WAT

Sample Request Payload

{"lineAmount":-6000,"accountCode":"901"}

{"lineAmount":6000,"accountCode":"631"}

Sample Response

{"Type":null,"Title":"Unauthorized","Status":401,"Detail":"AuthenticationUnsuccessful","Instance":"61b04110-6b52-4b8f-81de-910eee892e97","Extensions":{}}

We're using .Net to implement and we're able to get the refresh-token and access-token successfully on test environment.

Please what could be the issue why it's not working on the production environment ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the formatting of your headers as the instance id shows the error "There was no Bearer present in the Authorization header" in Xero's logs

Comment: The header format is fine. As we can get the refresh-token and the access-token on the test environment. It's only not working on the Production, we're using same configs we're using for the Xero trial account on test environment which is working fine.

We're getting back the access-token for the Bearer, But as soon as we push to production the call to get the access-token for the Bearer returns UnAuthorized.

Comment: Please can you raise a case with Xero Support via the support form here https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support. Can you include your client id and the date, time and timezone of the most recent error. An instance id would also be helpful